# Error "NameError: global name 'lqi' is not defined" al utilizar la función lqi() de control.matlab en python

Tags: python, matlab

necesito utilizar funciones de Matlab en python, específicamente funciones de teoría de control. Para ello estoy utilizando la documentacion respectiva encontrada en el siguiente link:
http://python-control.sourceforge.net/manual-0.5a/matlab_strings.html#lqr-lqg-design

Ahora bien, al intentar utilizar la funcion lqi() ob tengo el error:

"NameError: global name 'lqi' is not defined"

Parte del código es el siguiente:

import numpy as np
from control.matlab import *

def lqrlong(A,B,C,D):

```
Cnew2 = np.matrix([[1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1]])



Dnew2=np.matrix([[0,0],[0,0]])


n=np.size(B,0)# cantidad de filas
m=np.size(B,1)#cantidad decolumnas
print (n)
print (m)
Znm=np.zeros((n,m), dtype=int)
Znn=np.zeros((n,n), dtype=int)
Zmn=np.zeros((m,n), dtype=int)
Zmm=np.zeros((m,m), dtype=int)


Wlqrq=np.matrix([[0.01,0],[0,0.05]]);#Ref


Wlqrqb=np.matrix([[0.05,0,0,0,0],[0,0.01,0,0,0],[0,0,0.01,0,0],[0,0,0,0.01,0],[0,0,0,0,2.5]]);#Estados

Wlqrr=np.matrix([[20],[20]]);#Salidas

Q =[np.concatenate((Wlqrqb,Znm),axis=1),np.concatenate((Zmn,Wlqrq),axis=1)];
#print(Q)

#R =diag(Wlqrr);
R=np.matrix([[20,0],[0,20]]);#Salidas


sys = ss(A,B ,Cnew2,Dnew2 );

[Kr] =lqi(sys,Q,R);
```

AlonA=np.matrix([[0.068,-8.917,8.245,-9.779,0],[-0.979,-185.221,-0.051,-0.061,0],[1.686,-268.510,-3.814,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[-0.0062,0.999,0,-9.127,0]]);#A

BlonB=np.matrix([[-2.552,-0.283],[-2.312,0],[-24.53,0],[0,0],[0,0]]);#B

lqrlong(AlonA,BlonB,1,1)

Comment: Juan, tu código tiene algunos caracteres **";"**. Imagino que lo sacaste de otro lenguaje y lo fuiste adaptando. Por otra parte, de acuerdo a lo que revisé, la función **lqi** de matlab, parece no estar implementada en el módulo **control.matlab**.

Comment: Pero en el enlace adjunto en la sección lqr/lqg design aparece la función lqi.